# Java: Thread does not increment value of instance variable of class instance i passed

Tags: java, multithreading

I was expecting println in main method to return value 45, but it returns 0 instead.

`Main class:`

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyCounter counter = new MyCounter();
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new MyThread(counter));
    thread1.start();
    System.out.println(counter.getCount()); //Prints 0 :(
     }
}
```

`MyThread class:`

```
class MyThread implements Runnable{

    MyCounter counter;

    public MyThread(MyCounter counter){
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            counter.inc(i);
        }
    }
}
```

`MyCounter:`

```
class MyCounter {

    private int count = 0;

    public void inc(int i){
        count += i;
    }

    public void dec(){
        count--;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: put thread1.join() after thread1.start();

Comment: In addition to adding join(), your counter is not thread safe. It will work with just one thread. But if multiple thread share same counter then volaaaa... So use mutex.

Answer (score 0):

There might be two possible situations.

1. When you call `System.out.println` in the main thread, `thread1` has not incremented the counter.
2. `thread1` has incremented the counter, but the main thread did not notice it because of memory barrier.

You can add [`thread1.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) before calling `System.out.println`.

> When a thread terminates and causes a Thread.join in another thread to
>   return, then all the statements executed by the terminated thread have
>   a happens-before relationship with all the statements following the
>   successful join. The effects of the code in the thread are now visible
>   to the thread that performed the join.

Which can make sure:

1. `System.out.println` will be executed after incrementing the counter.
2. The main thread can get the updated counter.

Answer (score -1):

Your main thread ends before new thread do anything. Delay execution a little bit.

```
MyCounter counter = new MyCounter();
Thread thread1 = new Thread(new MyThread(counter));
thread1.start();
Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println(counter.getCount()); //Prints 0 :(
```

This is not the best example to ilustrate multithreading IMHO.

Comment: Even the main thread is delayed, it is still not guranteed to get the updated counter.